# Can we use future continuous in the following sentence?

Tags: tenses, future

"I have instructed that the cheque latest have to be issued by 15th every month, is there any problems? Please voiced out earlier if there's any issues in future. This will be the last time I'll be reminding on this."

I would be wonder, whether the last sentence is correct or no!? "I'll be reminding on this" i think it must be "I am reminding on this" or "I reminded on this".

Thank

Comment: I don't think any of the expressions you suggest about "remind" is the one you should be using. However, reading the rest of the instructions I'm under the impression there's a lot to be changed, and that the verb "remind" is not the most serious problem...

Comment: Oh know it, but i would like to know the last one, this is not my sentence, this is boss sentence :D

Comment: "I have instructed that the cheques have to be issued by 15th every month latest, is there any problem? Please voice out earlier if there are any issues in future. This was the last time I was reminding on this." is it right?

Comment: I'd say "In the future, please let us know in due time if there are any issues. This is the last time I'll remind you about/of this."

Comment: well, why we must use future tense!? I means, why you said "I'll remind you about/of this" why you did not say "I reminded you about/of this", thanks!

Comment: There are several problems with this paragraph from an AmE speaker's point of view. However, the spelling of the word "check" tells me this is probably meant to be BE instead, so I'll let those familar with that dialect go at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paola mentioned, there are other things in the sentence that needs reviewing/changed. Try a variant from the examples below for what you are trying to convey:

1. I have instructed to issue the check latest by the 15th of every month. Please let my know if if you are not clear about the instructions. I will not remind this again.
2. This is my final reminder to issue the check(s) latest by 15th of every month. Please let me know right now if you are unclear about the instructions.
3. I am not going to remind you again on issuing the check latest by 15th of every month. Let me know right now if there is something you are not clear about.

There can be countless other variants to convey the same message.

Comment: oh i got why he has used future continues, he wanted to say,"This would be the last time, I won't be reminding on this." In grammar point of view this sentence is right, am I right?

Comment: high level gist of your comment: yes. and have a look here for further reading: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_future-perfect.htm